Converting a binary to a string variable in Polars (Python Library) with non-UTF-8 characters
I'm having trouble manipulating a dataset in Python which has non-UTF-8 characters. The strings are imported as a binary.  But I am having issues converting the binary columns to strings where a cell has non UTF-8 characters.
A minimal working example of my issue is
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd

pd_df = pd.DataFrame([[b"bob", b"value 2", 3], [b"jane", b"\xc4", 6]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])
df = pl.from_pandas(pd_df)

column_names = df.columns

# Loop through the column names
for col_name in column_names:
    # Check if the column has binary values
    if df[col_name].dtype ==pl.Binary:
        # Convert the binary column to string format
        print(col_name)
        df = df.with_columns(pl.col(col_name).cast(pl.String))


This throws an error when converting column b.   For a solution, I'm fine converting any non-utf 8 characters to blanks.
Have tried many other suggestions for conversion in online suggestions, but I can't get any of them to work.

There's no such thing as non-UTF-8 characters. All the bytes are encoded with a specific encoding. If the bytes contain C4, this isn't UTF8, period. It may be Latin1 or something else but NOT UTF8.  You'll have to find what the actual encoding of the source data is. You could use a library or tool like chardet to find possible encodings based on the byte values and statistics

Where does the data come from? How is it loaded? That's where you need to specify the correct encoding. For example, you can use pd.read_csv(... ,encoding='latin1') instead of using the default UTF-8

Note: Python uses Unicode (with few caveats), not UTF-8. So instead of reading the data as UTF-8, give the importer/reader the expected encoding. (and the same with output). And forget encoding on main (and most) part of code.

Thank for all for the comments.  The suggested solutions below did work.  And for the underlying issue, I was importing a SAS dataset with the read_sas function.  I was not using the encoding parameter for this function, so that has allowed me to import the string variables as string in the first place + avoid a latter conversion step

This solution also relies on applying python's native bytes.decode to all elements in the columns of type pl.Binary. Unfortunately, we cannot yet use polars' native expression API for this, but need to call pl.Expr.map_elements instead.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col(pl.Binary).map_elements(
        lambda bytes: bytes.decode(errors='ignore'),
        return_dtype=pl.String
    )
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌──────┬─────────┬─────┐
│ a    ┆ b       ┆ c   │
│ ---  ┆ ---     ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str     ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪═════════╪═════╡
│ bob  ┆ value 2 ┆ 3   │
│ jane ┆         ┆ 6   │
└──────┴─────────┴─────┘


So it seems you are using a wrong enconding (probably it is not UTF-8 but something else - you need to figure that out). But coming back to your original request, you can still do that and just ignore decoding errors (you will get blank values in that case) by applying a lambda which decodes char by char. But as you can think this is just a workaround and not really the right thing to do:
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd

pd_df = pd.DataFrame([[b"bob", b"value 2", 3], [b"jane", b"\xc4", 6]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])
df = pl.from_pandas(pd_df)

column_names = df.columns

# Loop through the column names
for col_name in column_names:
    # Check if the column has binary values
    if df[col_name].dtype == pl.Binary:
        # Convert the binary column to string format, handling non UTF8 characters
        df = df.with_columns(
            pl.col(col_name).map_elements(
                lambda x: x.decode(errors='ignore') if isinstance(x, bytes) else x
            ).alias(col_name)
        )

print(df)

